# refactoring $rootScope.$apply in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my `MusicPlayer.js` Angular service  has a callback function wrapped in `$rootScope.$apply` that updates a specific object (`musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime`) and is shared to all other controllers ( via applying to `$rootScope`).

I understand that you'll ideally want to limit any `$rootScope` pollution, so i'm looking at possible refactoring options that take away calling apply methods to `$rootScope` but allows my updated object to be shared across multiple controllers.

My research indicates that i'll need to register the other controllers (i.e. `PlayerDashboardCtrl.js`, `PlaylistCtrl.js` and `AlbumListCtrl.js`) that  need my `currentPlaybackTime` object, but i'd like to understand what's the most efficient way of doing this.

Thank you.

```
 var setSong = function(song) {

    currentBuzzObject = new buzz.sound(song.audioUrl, {
        formats: ['mp3'],
        preload: true
    });

    currentBuzzObject.bind('timeupdate', function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = currentBuzzObject.getTime();  
        });
    });

    musicPlayer.currentSong = song;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to share data between controllers is to make a `service/factory` and get data using these service from whichever controller you want. You will have to `inject` this service in all the controllers where you want to access them.

This egghead video will give you a clear understanding: [Share data between controllers](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers)

Stackoverflow question similar to this: [Stackoverflow answers to sharing data between controllers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Live Demo: [Fiddle to show data sharing.](http://jsfiddle.net/27mk1n1o/)